# Why can debugger give another result than common run in C#?

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm working on this task on CodeWars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5667e8f4e3f572a8f2000039/train/csharp.

My code should turn string like this *"ZpglnRxqenU"* in something like this *"Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu"*.

But I'm getting an error: *"Z-Pp-Ggg-Lll-..."*. It returns three letters "l" instead of four letters.

I tried this code on my PC and the result is the same. But when I use debugger it shows the correct result. How can that be?
Here's my code:

```
using System;
public class Accumul 
    {
        public static String Accum(string s) 
      {
        string result = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
         {
           result += char.ToUpper(s[i]);
           for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
           {
              result += char.ToLower(s[i]);
           }
           result += "-";
         }
         result = result.Remove(s.Length - 1, 1);
         return result;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably checking `result` when you debug.
But the error is only at the end `result = result.Remove(s.Length - 1, 1);`
`s.Length - 1` removes the 10th character, you need `result.Length -1`.